# HELP $q=mysql_query($sel) or die(mysql_error()) HELP

Tags: database

My website is crashing on this line of code. It happened after we updated to the latest version of WordPress. It hadn't been updated for the previous 5 years. So its not surprising. I'm new to WordPress so I have no idea how to fix. 
HELP
HELP
HELP

Comment: This is not necessarily a WordPress issue per se, but an underlying PHP one. The original MySQL extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5 and removed completely in PHP 7.

Comment: @MrWhite is right, you should upgrade your server/hosting. the minimum is MySQL version 5.6 or greater OR MariaDB version 10.0 or greater. See requirements:  https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/

Answer (score 0):

This is more like a server problem, it seems like your server is very old. WordPress requirements change over time to stay up to date and provide a fast and stable experience and also more features.

As of this post, the WordPress server (minimum) requirements are the following:
PHP 5.2.4+
MySQL 5.0+

Recommended is:
PHP version 7.2 or greater.
MySQL version 5.6 or greater OR MariaDB version 10.0 or greater.
HTTPS support

See documentation: https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/